# Video doesn't show up when using dual monitor on Acer netbook

Tags: video, ubuntu-netbook, multiple-monitors, acer

So whenever I plug my monitor into my Acer netbook for dual monitor functionality, I cannot watch videos on VLC (window is black) or use the webcam on Skype. Does anyone have a work-around for this? Or maybe this is a bug that needs to be submitted?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like hardware acceleration isn't working on the second device. What video card do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I wanted to watch a DVD but VLC couldn't play it, so when I installed the restricted libraries for watching DVDs, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, and this is only my opinion. If something requires a work around, then in fact it is a bug. Work arounds are great, but don't help anyone in the long run. Just my opinion. If you could, it would be great if you did file a bug report.

Comment: you are right. I think what I'm really looking for is a fix.

Comment: When you file the bug, can you post a link here. I'd like to follow it. I have an Acer Aspire One Netbook and I can help you and the bug tacking by verifying the fixes and provide stats etc using my own machine.